# How to enable responsiveness to Plotly-Dash app within an Iframe?

Tags: html, css, iframe, responsive-design, plotly-dash

I have created a dash app, that is hosted to serve on the Heroku server. The dash app is completely responsive. If I access it on a mobile, iPad, desktop,.. the plot size auto-scales and fits the width of the window. This is perfect. However, embedding this dash app URL in an iframe of my website, the plot's responsiveness is lost. It does not autoscale to fit the width of the iframe.

How to ensure that the iframe and the plot responsively auto-scales to fit the width of the window?

My dash app: https://isb-hpi.herokuapp.com/

My iframe code:

```
<div class="iframe-container">
<iframe class="responsive-iframe" src="https://isb-hpi.herokuapp.com/"></iframe>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.iframe-container {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 45%;
}


.responsive-iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

code to construct plot:

```
from warnings import showwarning
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

config = {'responsive': True}

figq1 = px.line(dfq1, x="month", y="final_Index", color="Bedroom",template='presentation', line_shape='spline', labels={"Bedroom": "Type"}, category_orders={"Bedroom":['1bhk', '2bhk', '3bhk']})
figq1.update_traces(line=dict(width=1))
figq1.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=dfqa1.month,
        y=dfqa1.final_Index,
        mode="lines",
        line=go.scatter.Line(color="gray", width=2),
        showlegend=True, name='all')
)
figq1.update_layout(width=750,height=500, autosize=True)
figq1.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(
        rangeslider=dict(
            visible=True,
            thickness=.05
        ),
        type="date"
    )
)
figq1.update_layout(
    xaxis_title="Time",    yaxis_title="final_Index",legend_title="",
    font=dict(
        family="Courier New, monospace",
        size=11,
        color="RebeccaPurple"
    ),  legend=dict(
    orientation="h",
    yanchor="bottom",
    y=1.05,
    xanchor="right",
    x=1
)
)
figq1.update_yaxes(
    title=' '
)
figq1.layout.legend.itemsizing = 'constant'
figq1.layout._config= config

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
colors = {
    'background': '#111111',
    'text': '#7FDBFF'
}

server=app.server
app.css.append_css({
    'external_url': 'https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css'
})
server=app.server

tabs_styles = {'zIndex': 99, 'display': 'inlineBlock', 'height': '4vh', 'width': '12vw',
               'position': 'fixed', "background": "#323130", 'top': '12.5vh', 'left': '7.5vw',
               'border': 'grey', 'border-radius': '4px'}

tab_style = {
    "background": "#323130",
    'text-transform': 'uppercase',
    'color': 'white',
    'border': '#A9A9A9',
    'font-size': '9px',
    'font-weight': 600,
    'align-items': 'center',
    'justify-content': 'center',
    'border-radius': '4px',
    'padding':'6px'
}

tab_selected_style = {
    "background": "#A9A9A9",
    'text-transform': 'uppercase',
    'color': 'white',
    'font-size': '9px',
    'font-weight': 600,
    'align-items': 'center',
    'justify-content': 'center',
    'border-radius': '4px',
    'padding':'6px'
}
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Tabs(id='tabs-example', value='tab-1', children=[
        dcc.Tab(label='India', value='tab-1',style=tab_style, selected_style=tab_selected_style),
    html.Div(id='tabs-example-content')
])
@app.callback(Output('tabs-example-content', 'children'),
              Input('tabs-example', 'value'))
def render_content(tab):
    if tab == 'tab-1':
        return html.Div([
    html.Div([
        html.Div([
            dcc.Graph(id='g2', figure=figq1)
        ], className="row", style={
            'width': 750,
            "display": "block",
            "margin-left": "auto",
            "margin-right": "auto",
            }),
    ], className="row")
])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

Edit:
[image: responsiveness snapshot]

Comment: You've shared the irrelevant part of your implementation and didn't share the relevant one. Your problem is related to what you're serving (even if it works when included in regular markup). Here's how something served properly looks like when embeded: https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/sLdwq1ah/. Also take note your server doesn't currently allow cross-origin embedding. You have to set it specifically to allow embedding from whatever domain you're trying to do it, or your app will not be visible.

Comment: One more thing: you're claiming the regular serve is resized properly and is responsive, but that's not what I'm [seeing here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFPaz.png). Maybe you should describe in clear what you mean by *"responsivess"* and *"This is perfect"*, as your definition seems to differ from the common usage of those terms in similar contexts.

Comment: Hi @tao, thanks for writing. I am new to web designing concepts. I visited my hosted app link and clicked inspect. I checked the responsiveness and the plot size scaled accordingly and it fit to window width. Please check the new screenshot added. I am trying to achieve downsizing and upsizing the plot within the iframe relative to window width.

Comment: I visited the JSfiddle site shared by you and tried to replace Wikipedia example with my app-url. The plot doesn't downscale and it displays only a small portion of the plot within the iframe. Here the iframe is being responsive, but not the component inside it. However, the URL when visited outside the iframe displayed responsive behavior. Im confused. Can you help? https://jsfiddle.net/y1cjwd5b/

Comment: I showed you how wikipedia renders inside your `<iframe>` (or a pretty similar one) to demonstrate the problem is not in the code you shared (you shared the code ***outside*** the `<iframe>`). The problem is the code ***inside*** the `<iframe>`, which you have not shared. That's what you need to share if you want anyone to be able to suggest a fix.

Comment: the code inside the iframe is python code to construct the plotly chart.

Comment: I added the code to construct one plot within one tab of the app. Please let me know if it was of any help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230556/discussion-between-tao-and-sachin-kumar-s).

Answer (score 1):

When building dash apps with responsive layouts,
always use:

```
config = {'responsive': True}
autosize=True
```

Never set the width and height explicitly as you can see in my code to construct the plot.